# Python Flask SocketIO Multiprocessing different Class Functions

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing, uart, flask-socketio

I am new to Flask and was wondering if we could run different processes belonging to different classes running in parallel to Flask app. My code structure is very similar to this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import *
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import serial
import time, datetime

# App config.
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7d441f27d441f27567d441f2b6176a'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app)

class serial_read_Process():

    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 0.2
        self.port = serial.Serial ( port='/dev/ttyTHS2', baudrate=115200, 
                                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)

    def serial_read (self):
        # read UART and process the incoming serial data and send it to webpage
        currtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        socketio.emit('values', {'data1':data1, 'currtime':currtime}, namespace='/serial')
        time.sleep(self.delay)

class ProcessWebPageData():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.person_name = name
        self.delay = 0.2

    def process_data(self):
        # process the data received from the webpage
        time.sleep(self.delay)


@socketio.on('my_event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    name_val= message.get('name')   
    ProcessDataObj = ProcessWebPageData()
    process2 = mp.Process(target=ProcessDataObj.process_data, args=(name_val,)) # For Processing the data received from the web page
    if not process2.is_alive():
        thread2.daemon = True
        thread2.start()


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def load():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    uart_read = serial_read_Thread()
    process1 = mp.Process(target=uart_read.serial_read) # For Reading UART values
    process1.daemon = True
    if not process1.is_alive():
        process1.start()
        print("process started")

if __name__== "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

I am continuously getting the values from UART when I print those in serial_read function I see them being printed. I do not see them on the web page which I send via socketio.emit(). I have  a Javascript code where I receive the values and use it to display on HTML webpage. Also is this the correct way to do?  Any inputs would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: There is not enough information for me to tell you what's wrong. First of all, are you using eventlet or gevent on this application? Those are unlikely to be compatible with reading from a serial port, which is a blocking operation. I suggest you see if things work better in "threading" mode. Another problem, multiprocessing is not supported under Flask-SocketIO either, so use threads instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Miguel. I am not using any of the eventlet or gevent. Running on the Flask development web server. Initially I had 2 threads instead of 2 process and it worked well. But then I want to introduce 2 more functions which are independent of this. Basically those 2 functions are sending and receiving data from the socket which connects to TCP server. So I converted these threads to processes.

Comment: The problem is that the Socket.IO server cannot span multiple processes. When you emit from one of those processes, the `socketio` variable that you are using is not the same that is running the server, variables cannot be shared across processes. You may want to read the [Emitting from an External Process](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process) section of the documentation for a way to do what you need, but be aware that the set up to do that is more complex.